# Rational clearcase explorer throws error like "Encountered an improper argument"

Tags: clearcase-ucm, clearcase-remote-client

I am using Rational clearcase explorer to view VOB. I was created my dynamic view in view server,But I am not able to access my directory or folder. when I tried to access it throws an error like "Encountered an improper argument" in Rational clearcase explorer dialog box.

Comment: PS: The vob is mounted. But the Network drive which has vob is in disconnected state. I don't know why it is shows disconnected after mount vob's.

Answer (score 0):

In a ClearCase Explorer, when accessing any folder, you must first access the vob.

That means you need to make sure the vob is mounted:

```
cleartool mount \myVob
# unix:
cleartool mount /vobs/myVob
```

If the vob is visible, but a folder is not accessible, you need to check its status as seen from its parent folder:

```
cd /myview/myVob/parent/folder
cleartool ls
```

That will give you a clue as to why you cannot access the subfolder.

As mentioned in the technote "["Encountered an improper argument" error displayed in ClearCase Native GUI](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21635518)", it can be a right issue:

> If a principal has not been granted access to a VOB, an attempt to access the VOB from IBM® Rational® ClearCase Explorer returns the error, "Encountered an improper argument."
>
> ### Resolving the problem
>
> This error might imply insufficient permissions.
>
> To determine the effective ACL on the object, use the command

```
cleartool describe -eacl vob:\vobtag \vobtag
```

---

For ClearCase 8, [you also have this bug](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM90756):

> When accessing a file or directory in the IBM Rational ClearCase
>   GUIs, for example, ClearCase Explorer or the Version Tree
>   Browser, **that has permissions of 770**, you will receive an error:
>   'Encountered an improper argument' rather than 'Access Denied'
>   or 'Permission Denied' if you are not a member of the group that
>   owns the element.
>
> A fix is available in ClearCase versions  8.0.0.8 and 8.0.1.1

Comment: Hi vonc, Thanks for the reply.. The vob is mounted. But the Network drive which has vob is in disconnected state. I don't know why it is shows disconnected after mount vob's. can you please Help me ?

Comment: @MohamedHanish What ClearCase Doctro mentions? What version of ClearCase are you using?

Comment: @MohamedHanish I meant "ClearCase Doctor" (like the one you see in http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21366273)